# Is the integral of the curvature the variation of the parallel transport even if there are corners on the on the border of the region?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curvature

I'm studying differential geometry using the book "Differential Geometry of Curves & Surfaces - Manfredo P. do Carmo", and the following doubt came to me.

Let $S\subset \mathbb{R}^3$ a surface, considere $x:U \rightarrow S$ be an isothermal parametrization at a point $p ∈ S$, and let $R ⊂x(U)$ be a simple region without vertices, containing $p$ in its interior.

Let $α: [0,l] →x(U)$ be a curve parametrized by arc length $s$ such that the trace of $α$ is the boundary of $R$. Let $w_0$ be a unit vector tangent to $S$ at $α(0)$ and let $w(s)$, $s ∈ [0,l]$, be the parallel transport of $w_0$ along $α$. Note that

\begin{align}
0 &= \int_{0}^{l} \left[\frac{Dw}{ds} \right]ds\\
&= \int_{0}^{l} \frac{1}{2\sqrt{EG}} \left\{G_u \frac{dv}{dt} - E_v \frac{du}{dt}  \right\}ds + \int_{0}^{l} \frac{d\varphi}{ds}ds\\
&= - \int \int_R K d\sigma + \varphi(l) - \varphi(0) 
\end{align}

where $\varphi = \varphi(s)$ is a differentiable determination of the angle from $x_u$ to $w(s)$, $E = \langle x_u,x_u\rangle$,  $G = \langle x_v,x_v\rangle$, $K$ is the Gaussian curvature and  $\left[\frac{Dw}{dt}\right]$ is the algebraic value of the covariant derivative of $w$ at $t$.

It follows that $\varphi(l)−\varphi(0)$ = $\Delta \varphi$ is given by

$$\Delta \varphi = \int \int_R K dS. $$

**I would like to know if $R\subset x(U)$ be a simple region WITH vertices the result still holds. If so how to prove it?**

Comment: Do the integration in piecewise fashion over each segment between the vertices.

Comment: You will or course get a jump every time you cross a vertex from one segment of the boundary to the next, determined by the turning angle at the vertex.

Comment: @user7530 - no you won't. The transported vector will change continuously, though not smoothly, across vertices. You start each new segment with the same vector that was the result of parallel transport over the last segment.

Comment: @PaulSinclair right, the *vector* will change continuously, but the *angle* will not

Comment: @user7530: No, we're looking at the angle with the frame vector field $x_u$, not with the tangent vector to $\alpha$. ... It's instructive to look at the example of a geodesic triangle (say with all right angles) on the unit sphere.